# Automatically add class to link based on link text

Tags: posts, css, links

I am wondering whether it is possible to automatically add a class to a series of links based on the link text.

The scenario is as follows:

I am displaying a list of links on a page in Wordpress that link to other posts - in this case a custom post type for a schedule. The posts all have time based names, i.e. '12:23' '12:53' '13:23' and so on.

This generates a list of links like this:

```
<a href="departuretime/1223">12:23</a>

<a href="departuretime/1253">12:53</a>

<a href="departuretime/1323">13:23</a>
```

Where each link links to a full custom post associated to display that schedule.

I would like to format these links based on the current time and to do this I need the class to be automatically generated based on the link text.

```
<a class='1223' href="departuretime/1223">12:23</a>

<a class='1253' href="departuretime/1253">12:53</a>

<a class='1323' href="departuretime/1323">13:23</a>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: The list of links is automatically generated by the 'Display Posts Shortcode' plugin using the shortcode:

[display-posts post_type="schedule" order="ASC" posts_per_page="25" wrapper="div" wrapper_class="bus-times-table-items today"]

Comment: Ok as this is a plugin I would first ask the creators or read the documentation for a filter or a hook action. Another approach would be a JS that will look on the href attribute and addClass the integer(time).

Comment: Thanks @Drupalizeme - I have gone through the documentation, unfortunately there is nothing to that effect in there.

Comment: The shortcode does provide a unique Identifier so we can target that on JS? For example an ID or a class name with an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want a visual indicator for departures relevant on the current time.

One solution will be using Javascript and provide a way for the element to be identified as passed or active schedule time.

**HTML**

```
<div id="myElement">
  <a href="https://myawesomenewsite.com/departuretime/1253">1253</a>
  <a href="https://myawesomenewsite.com/departuretime/1255">1255</a>
  <a href="https://myawesomenewsite.com/departuretime/0955">0955</a>
  <a href="https://myawesomenewsite.com/departuretime/2213">2213</a>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// find elements
var rootElements = $("#myElement a");

rootElements.each(function(index, item){

 var url = item.href,
 arr_split = url.split("/"),
 arr_index = arr_split.length-1,
 departureTime = arr_split[arr_index],
 date = new Date(),
 myTime = date.getHours()+''+date.getMinutes();

 //add your class like this
 item.classList.add(myTime);

 //but you can also spice it up a bit
if(departureTime>myTime){
     item.classList.add("you_have_time");
}else{
    item.classList.add("you_dont_have_time");
}

});
```

**CSS**

```
.you_have_time{
  color:green;
}

.you_dont_have_time{
  color:red;
}
```

And ofcourse the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pq4Lxug6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do this for styling reasons it's not necessary to add a class, you can style based on the href attribute alone using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). For example, to style a link where the href URL ends with `1253` you can use:

```
a[href$="1253"] {
    color: red;
}
```

On the off chance you have a different link that also ends in that number you could specify the styling for a link that ends in `1253` *and* starts with `departuretime`:

```
a[href^="departuretime"][href$="1253"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my plan is to use a script that then styles the link based on the the current time.

So that schedule times in the past are greyed out for example.